# NG-Model and Array - How it works?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

I supposed to have the following code:

.JS

```
angularcomponents.controller('CountryCntrl', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
    $scope.countries = {
                    'India': {
                        'Maharashtra': ['Pune', 'Mumbai', 'Nagpur', 'Akola'],
                        'Madhya Pradesh': ['Indore', 'Bhopal', 'Jabalpur'],
                        'Rajasthan': ['Jaipur', 'Ajmer', 'Jodhpur']
                    },
                    'USA': {
                        'Alabama': ['Montgomery', 'Birmingham'],
                        'California': ['Sacramento', 'Fremont'],
                        'Illinois': ['Springfield', 'Chicago']
                    },
                    'Australia': {
                        'New South Wales': ['Sydney'],
                        'Victoria': ['Melbourne']
                    }
                };
}]);
```

and the html:

```
<div ng-controller="CountryCntrl">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <select id="country" ng-model="states" ng-options="country for (country, states) in countries">
            <option value=''>
                Select
            </option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <small><em>Country</em></small>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <select id="state" ng-disabled="!states" ng-model="cities" ng-options="state for (state,city) in states">
            <option value=''>
                Select
            </option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <small><em>States</em></small>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <select id="city" ng-disabled="!cities || !states" ng-model="city">
            <option value=''>
                Select
            </option> 
            <option ng-repeat="city in cities" value='[[city]]'>
                [[city]]
            </option>
        </select>  
        <br>
        <small><em>City</em></small>      
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't understand how it is binding the right values for cities, countries and states. In my $scope there is not any label to identify it.

Does it depend on the format of the array?

Comment: Can you give me in a fiddler demo?

Comment: Perhaps the question is a bit unclear, are you asking why the select box is bound to the right city, states and country? The fact that your object has been created with the relationships means that they are?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define variables in your javascript (though you may prefer to) - when you declare a ng-model, a variable is created on $scope for you. So your country select is bound to a model states, which has no value initially.

Because you did `country for (country, states)`, the label of that select is the array key, which is the country name. The value is bound to the array value. So when you select a country, $scope.states is populated with the full array corresponding to that country.

So now `$scope.states` has an array in it, which allows `ng-options="state for (state,city) in states"` to build a selector, and so on.

You can see it happening by displaying the contents of your model variables. Here is a fiddle to show that: https://jsfiddle.net/wbpm8bc7/

As you can see, initially it shows nothing as those variables are empty. But as you make a selection, they are populated with arrays.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I could imagine it. So, if I change the structure of the object everything will be different in the select. Is it all right?

Comment: Yes exactly, your selects will correspond to the array or sub-array however you have set it up.